# change the interval of dates in x-axis (ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two `dataframes` with columns `DateTime`, `Date` and `parameter`. Both `dfs` have both the columns where the values for the column `Date` are same and the values for the column `parameter` are different.  Both the `dfs` have hourly averaged value for the given parameter, lets say `V1`.

I want to plot the value for both `V1` from both `dfs` together using `ggplot2` with `5 days` interval in the `x-axis`. As all the dates are coming in the axis, the plot is unreadable.
Here is the code i am using

```
ggplot() +
geom_point(data=df1, aes(Date, V1), color='blue') +
geom_point(data=df2, aes(Date, V1), color='red') +
theme_bw() +
scale_x_date(breaks="10 days", limits= as.Date(c("2012-12-15", "2013-01-15")))
```

`scale_x_date` doesn't seem to work. It is giving the following error

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Comment: I had encountered similar error, while trying to add text annotations to my plot made by ggplot, with x-axis in date format. When I converted the date to numeric, I got rid of this error.

So for your problem, I would suggest that you can try :   ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=df1, aes(Date, V1), color='blue') +  
    geom_point(data=df2, aes(Date, V1), color='red') +  
    theme_bw() +  
    scale_x_date(breaks="10 days", limits= as.numeric(as.Date(c("2012-12-15", "2013-01-15"))))

Comment: @KumarManglam with the use of `as.numeric` i am getting error `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`.

Comment: I looked into the documentation of `scale_x_date` function. I see that you are using breaks instead of date_breaks. I think if you replace the breaks parameter with date_breaks, your code should work.

Comment: @KumarManglam I got the following error `Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "date", identity, breaks = breaks,  : unused argument (date_breaks = "10 days")`

Comment: @ShretaGhimire It would be easier to provide a solution if you provide sample data for `df1` and `df2`.  However, I think you are looking for is what Kumar Manglam was suggesting and here is a code snippet (i.e. the change to make): `scale_x_date(date_breaks="10 days", limits= as.Date(c("2012-12-15", "2013-01-15")))`